# CSS 100% width instead of auto

Tags: jquery, html, css, popup

I'm making notification popups, that pop from bottom left. There are 2 divs: container "named" `.divPopups` and the popup named `.divPopupNote`. Their CSS is this:

```
.divPopups{
background-color: transparent;
position: fixed;
top: auto;
right: auto;
}

.divPopups .divPopupNote {
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: orange;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Also, I have a `Global.css`, in which I said:

```
body, header, footer, div, p, table,
 th, tr, td, ul, ol, li, input, button, img, select, label, iframe {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: inherit;
    font: inherit;
}
```

The `Global.css` is included first, so every other class overrides these properties.

The way I append popup:

```
    // SHOW POPUP
    $(".divPopups").append('<div class="divPopupNote errNo' + 
    errorNo + '" onclick="$(this).remove();"' +
    'style="background-color:' + backgroundColor + ';">' + message + '</div>');

// SLIDE IN FROM BOTTOM
$(".errNo" + errorNo).css("margin-bottom", -$(".errNo" + errorNo).outerHeight() + "px");
$(".errNo" + errorNo).animate({ opacity: '1', marginBottom: '10px' }, popupSpeed);
```

**The result that I'm getting:** [image]

**The result that want:** [image]

I get the same result if the largest popup is on top of smaller ones.

**I've tried** removing `padding` and `margin`, setting `left`, `rignt` to auto, using `jQuery` to set `$(popupID).width($(popupID).width());`, doing the same but with temporary variable in between. If I set `width` to auto, nothing changes. If I set `width` to (lets say) `200px`, then all popups **are** `200px` in width, but I want their `width` to be `auto`.

I don't understand what is making the popup's width be the same as the one from largest popup.

Comment: make divPopupNote  `display:inline-block`

Comment: `display: inline-block` does the trick

Comment: wow. it helped. definitely need to google differences in display. anyway, thanks. Now, they do stack next to one another if short enough, but I just added a `</br>` at the end of appending in jQuery, and it works well now.

Comment: Is there another way? I get a little stutter when animating with `</br>`. Some other `display` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your comment to the question you can do the following:

You need 3 divs

1 `div` to hold all the Notes (CSS: position:fixed; bottom:0; left:0)

1 `div` to wrap the note (CSS: display:block;) so they don't align side by side.

1 `div` for you text (CSS: display:inline-block;)

[Take a look at this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zxkx0xvf/)

HTML

```
<div class="divPopups">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="divPopupNote">Test 1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="divPopupNote">Test 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.divPopups {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.divPopups .divPopupNote {
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper {
  width:100%;
  display:block;
}
```